# rewrite php urls into a different variable

Tags: php, variables, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have 2 variables, $id and $product_name

I have urls for different products eg:

```
website.co.uk/product.php?id=123456
```

how can I change this to the product name variable:

```
website.co.uk/product.php?id=name+of+product
```

can this be done in php or will I have to use mod rewrite?

to something like

```
website.co.uk/product/name-of-product    ?
```

I have seen this from another post:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

if id=$1 in the line above, how does it know which variable to choose from out of $id and $product_name ?  Where do I specify which variable it should use?

---

I now have website.co.uk/product.php?id=123456&name=name-of-product

and would like to rewrite this to:

```
website.co.uk/123456/name-of-product
```

or

```
website.co.uk/product/123456/name-of-product
```

Comment: why don't you change the way product.php parses the id-field? just lookup the product by name instead of id...

Comment: you can create 2 rules one for numbers in param and another for string and on this basis you can differ on the php

Comment: It can be done either in mod_rewrite or PHP depends on you.

Comment: by product name could be a problem because there might be 2 products with the same name in the database - i could add a unique index for that

Answer (score 3):

mod_rewrite is not able to summon unknown information out of thin air. If you have a numeric id in your url, it cannot summon a product name out of thin air. If you use the pretty url `/product/name-of-product` you'll need to look up the name of the product in your database:

Use something like this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)$ /product.php?name=$1 [L]
```

And this in your php file:

```
<?php
  if( isset( $_REQUEST['id'] ) ) {
    $name = getNameFromId( intval( $_REQUEST['id'] ) );
    header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
    header( "Location: /product/{$name}" );
    exit();
  } else if( isset( $_REQUEST['name'] ) ) {
    $row = getRowFromName( $_REQUEST['name'] );
    if( $row === NULL ) {
      require( "404.php" );
      exit();
    }
    doStuff( $row );
  } else {
    //The heck? Neither of those set?
    require( "404.php" );
    exit();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify which variable to use by subpattern which is defined by () and numbered by $1 $2 in url

You can use something like

```
RewriteRule ^product/(/w+)/([A-Za-z]+)?$ product.php?id=$1&product_name=$2 [NC,L]
```

- `/w+` will fit 0-9A-Za-z which defines your $id
- `[A-Za-z]+` will work for product name

You can get these variables in PHP using `$_GET['id']` to get id or `$_GET['product_name']` to get product name.

Comment: do I need anything else before this rule in htaccess? I have this before: Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options +Indexes  
RewriteEngine On

Comment: these two lines should be okay depends on server's configuration.

Comment: and the above should rewrite the url to product/product_name  or product/id/product_name ?

Comment: you can put both it's up to you :)

Comment: its not working for some reason - maybe ive left something out in htaccess?